# Visual Studio 2015 RC fails to create any solution on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

Trying to create a new solution with VS 2015RC on Windows 10 I'm facing with an error:

```
Collection type must derive from ICollection<T>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These steps helped me to solve a problem:

- Close Visual Studio;
- Launch Visual Studio Developer command prompt as administrator;
- Run *"devenv.exe /setup"* command;
- Wait for execution ending;
- Restart VS.